# How to reset the column span of a widget in a QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgridlayout, columnspan

Is possible to set the column span of a `QLineEdit` box after it has been added to the layout? I have two `QLineEdit` boxes in a `QGridLayout` that are right next to each other horizontally. During the execution of some of my code, one of these boxes gets hidden. I would like to increase the column span where the hidden one was to avoid a weird gap at the end, and reduce it when needed.

I couldn't really find anything in the Qt documentation for this type of change beyond making the adjustment prior to adding the widget to the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There no method for resetting the row- or column-span after a widget has been added. However, `addWidget` can be called again on the same widget to achieve the same affect, because re-adding a widget to the same layout always implicitly removes it first. So something like this should work:

```
index = layout.indexOf(widget)
row, column = layout.getItemPosition(index)[:2]
layout.addWidget(widget, row, column, rowspan, colspan)
```

Here is a simple demo script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Toggle Edit')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.edit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit1.setPlaceholderText('One')
        self.edit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit2.setPlaceholderText('Two')
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit1, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit2, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.edit2.isHidden():
            self.setWidgetSpan(self.edit1, 1, 1)
            self.edit2.setHidden(False)
        else:
            self.edit2.setHidden(True)
            self.setWidgetSpan(self.edit1, 1, 2)

    def setWidgetSpan(self, widget, rowspan=1, colspan=1):
        layout = self.layout()
        index = layout.indexOf(widget)
        row, column = layout.getItemPosition(index)[:2]
        layout.addWidget(widget, row, column, rowspan, colspan)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but I didn't know that re-adding it would produce the desired effect. In my case I use a UI file, with some obvious changes, would this produce the same effect as well?

Comment: @AaronTomason. It should do - you just need a reference to the widget and the layout it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Try as said below.

When you add two `QLineEdit`, The `QGridLayout` dynamically creates two columns.

If you want extra columns for spanning use `QSpacerItem` and get extra columns. 
And you have to use `addItem(..,..,..)` of `QGridLayout` to add the spacer item to layout.

Between your two `QLineEdit` add spacers as shown below

```
spacer =  QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20)
layout.addItem(spacer,0,1)
```

Now if you add totak 4 spacers (for example) ,

```
spacer1 =  QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20)
layout.addItem(spacer1,0,2)

spacer2 =  QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20)
layout.addItem(spacer2,0,3)

spacer3 =  QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20)
layout.addItem(spacer3,0,4)
```

Now you have total 6 columns ------- with first `QLineEdit` (column 0), 4 spacers, last `QLineEdit` (column 5)

Now you can use `setColumnStretch(column,stretch)` to set the span of any line edit. Here I am trying to set span for last `QLineEdit`..as shown below. Spanned for 3 columns...

```
layout.setColumnStretch(5,3)
```

Hope this helps...